# Passing several primitive type members vs passing the outer mutable object - does functional programming express any preference?

Tags: functional-programming, java-native-interface, primitive, mutable

Functional programming attempts to ensure freedom from side-effects when invoking functions. Passing a mutable object as a parameter that is NOT returned gives a developer the ability to modify a non-returned object. In other words, side-effects are possible. If you pass primitive or immutable types, you are free from this extra layer of complexity when reasoning about a program. So **does good Functional Programming practice dictate anything when you have the choice between passing a mutable object vs passing primitive types**?

I am aware of the following properties of PURE functional programming:

- If all your types are immutable, it doesn't matter whether they are object types
- The mutable object cannot exist outside the scope where it is expected to be mutated

but in reality when you are dealing with huge code bases that have existed prior to Functional Programming gaining a newfound respect, you will often be dealing with data structures that have no corresponding immutable representation, and code will be a mixture of functional and imperative styles.

(Background - I am exposing C++ logic via Java Native Interface and am wondering when to avoid passing objects, but I'm not looking for an answer that directly applies to this use case. I just want some help applying good programming practice in a situation such as this)

Comment: The two options achieve very different things (unless you imply that the first option returns the new state, which opens a whole other can of worms). It seems to me one can't meaningfully compare them in general. Could you give a few examples?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't think of any reduced examples I can use to enhance my question. I'm just in the early stages of writing some JNI code for my proprietary database kernel and I notice that it's uncommon to pass objects. I'm wondering if there's a benefit to passing primitives apart from performance when reaching back to JVM objects from C++.

Comment: In my experience, its simpler to pass primitives than objects. Primitives translate directly between the layers, so there's no need to deconstruct the object using JNI. As we all know, JNI code is **ugly** and verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing that functional programming has to say about this matter is that you should ideally wrap all impure stuff that you expose, in a monad, such as the famous IO monad.

But this is probably too radical for your users.

Comment: ??  This seems to imply that `IO` and/or monads are magic fairy dust that is sprinkled on impure code to make it pure.  But that's probably not going to be the case.  Could you expand the answer to explain more about: 1) how using a monad would help, and 2) how to use a monad to achieve 1)?